# php mysql case when in cast date format

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the normal mysql query

```
SELECT SUM( Minutes ) as minsDecPrac, COUNT( DISTINCT (CAST(dtDateTime as DATE))) as playDecPrac FROM `tbl_atschool_timelog` WHERE `intuid` = 48876 AND `intGametypeId` = 2 AND `intGame` = 1
```

Here is the Output

```
minsDecPrac     playDecPrac   
17                 1
```

Here is the query using CASE WHEN

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN intGametypeId = 2 AND intGame =1 THEN Minutes ELSE 0 END) AS minsDecPrac COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN intGametypeId = 2 AND intGame =1 THEN  (CAST(dtDateTime as DATE)) ELSE 0 END) AS playDecPrac FROM `tbl_atschool_timelog` WHERE `intuid` = 48876
```

Here is the Output

```
minsDecPrac     playDecPrac   
17                 2
```

The problem is that if i use CASE WHEN, the output of "playDecPrac"(dtDateTime ) is wrong.
I don't know what i am wrong. Please help me if anybody knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clause here:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN intGametypeId = 2 AND intGame =1 THEN  (CAST(dtDateTime as DATE)) ELSE 0 END)
```

counts the 0 from `ELSE 0` as a distinct value, in addition to the dates. So the `COUNT(DISTINCT )` is one higher than it should be.

You might try `ELSE NULL`.